# Sql Query in Spark--->1. spark.sql("select * from titanic_csv").show() and 2. spark.sql("select count(*) from titanic_csv").show()

Tags: apache-spark

```
spark.sql("select * from titanic_csv").show()
spark.sql("select count(*) from titanic_csv").show()
```

what will be logical plan and how we can understand?

count(*) dag in spark ui

[image]

select * from table dag in spark ui

[image]

i would like to know how i can understand the plan of DAG

Answer (score 2):

1. How to get the plan

You can see physical plan in SparkUI. In sql tab find your query and look for details

[image]

You can also use explain method on your df

[image]

2. What is happening in your example

I think that the order of operations here is important, and in your case i think that you first called spark.sql("select * from titanic_csv").show() and then spark.sql("select count(*) from titanic_csv").show() (as stated in title) so i am going to stick to this

In case of select * dag is simple, there is fileScan because Spark need to load the data into memory and then you have mapPartitions which is connected to your show

In count(*) case the left branch is skipped because Spark is not removing imedietely shuffle files so there was no need to compute this part of query as needed data are already there from previous stage

If you go to the details of right branch (so stage 18) u will see that there is something like this

[image]

Which means that Spark is reading shuffle files and then in mapPartitions is doing actual count to give you the results you need

3. Some references

This is topic is huge and not easy to master but imo you can start from this articles:

https://dzone.com/articles/reading-spark-dags

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html